# Removed button still showing when running the 'Start Debugging' (F5) in microsoft visual c# 2010 express

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to Microsoft Visual C#, so I hope my following question is not sound stupid. I have removed a button from my form. However, it's still showing when I running the 'Start Debugging' (F5) in microsoft visual c# 2010 (see attach pictures for more details). does anyone know what is going there? and how can I solve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try rebuilding the project (or right click on project and select Clean and then try again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the option to continue to run when a build failure occurs is enabled.

Check setting  `"On Run, when build or deployment errors occur"` under `"Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build And Run"`.

If it is set to `"Launch old version"`, change it to `"Prompt to launch"`.  You will then be notified of the build error, which will allow you to correct the issue before running.

Comment: I cannot find those setting under Tools. It's because I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express?

Comment: @Jin: I've never used express (a little surprised that this setting isn't present in Express, to be honest).  If you're not getting any errors when you build, then this isn't the problem anyway.  I'm currently at a loss.

Comment: @Peter: Ye... This is really strange. So have no way I can find out what's going wrong there ? Possible that it's called to and history file? I'm not familar with MS Visual C# Envirement

Comment: @Peter: suprisingly that it's working now. hmm.... much be something strange happen in behind

Comment: @Jin: ah, in Express, you have to check the "Show all settings" checkbox in the lower left corner of the Tools -> Options dialog.  Still, without a build error, this shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: @Jin: perhaps you had the program still running when you were making the code changes and the build failed because it couldn't overwrite the existing executable and now that it is no longer running, it succeeded (assuming you didn't make any code changes to solve the problem)?

Answer (score 1):

Press `F6` to Build it, then `F5` to run.

Comment: I have tried F6 to build it before F5 to run it, but the result still the same

Comment: @Jin: were there any errors reported in the output window / error list when you build?

Comment: @Peter: I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express ... does it make difference??